# Cómo actualizar de un modelo a otro en ASP.NET MVC con Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Mi problema es el siguiente, quiero actualizar la cantidad del stock de un articulo cuando este sea agregado a una orden, para restarle la cantidad que fue ordenada. Tengo lo siguiente...

Tengo la propiedad `STOCK` en el modelo **Articulo**.

```
private int _STOCK;
public int STOCK
{
   get { return _STOCK; }
   set { _STOCK = value; }
}
```

La siguiente funcion es para actualizar (Aquí está el problema).

```
public Articulo UpdateStock(int id, int cant){
   using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext()){
       Articulo art = db.Articulos.Find(id);
       art.STOCK -= cant;
       db.Articulos.Update(art);
       return db.Articulos.Find(id);
   }
}
```

Luego, en el modelo **ArticuloOrden** creo una instancia de **Articulo** y ejecuto la función `UpdateStock()` pasansole el ID de la instancia y el valor de la cantidad como parámetros.

```
public virtual Articulo Articulo { get; set; }

private int _CANT;
public int CANT { 
   get{
      return _CANT;
   }
   set
   {
      _CANT = value;
      Articulo.UpdateStock(ART_ID, _CANT);
   } 
}
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si recibes los parámetros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te falta una llamada a `db.SaveChanges();` despues del `Update()`? I en la última linea, en vez de volver a buscar el articulo, creo que te bastaria con `return art;`

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult DescontarQTY_Remstar([Bind(Include = "Descripcion_Empleado,Description,Part_Number,SAP,id_Tipo,id_categoria,Imagen,QTY_Laboratorio,QTY_Remstar,Cantidad,Categoria")] Parte parte, [Bind(Include = "ID_registro,UserID,Part_Number,QTY_Laboratorio,QTY_Remstar,Cantidad,Fecha,Comentario,TipoDeMovimiento")] RegistroMovimiento registroMovimiento)
    {



        if (parte.QTY_Remstar <= 0 || parte.Cantidad > parte.QTY_Remstar || parte.Cantidad == null||parte.Cantidad<=0)
        {
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "No se Pudo Realizar El descuento.";
            return RedirectToAction("DescontarQTY_Remstar");
        }
        else
        {
            parte.QTY_Remstar = parte.QTY_Remstar - parte.Cantidad;
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update partes set [QTY Remstar]=" + parte.QTY_Remstar + " where [Part Number]='" + parte.Part_Number + "'");

            obj.RegistroMovimientos.Add(registroMovimiento);
            registroMovimiento.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            obj.SaveChanges();
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Descuento Realizado.";

            return Redirect(url: "http://nat/mantenimientonat/");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).